# Multisite installation without using domain root

Tags: multisite, directory

I would like to create a multisite installation using subdirectories, but I don't want any of the sites to use the domain root as their home URL.

I'd like to have the multisite install in
www.mydomain.com/multi/

Then my sites will be at
www.mydomain.com/site1/
www.mydomain.com/site2/

I've got a feeling that this isn't easily possible.
It seems like all sites within the network need to be subdomains of the core site (wherever that may be).

The documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory) indicates that this should be possible, but doesn't give any details.
I think that the only thing which is possible is to give your multisite a different directory to the installation, but the sub-sites will still need to sit within that.

I can create a multisite installation in /multi/, then create the sites, changing their site url afterwards to be outside the multisite root. This seems to work, but when I try to navigate to their admin areas I get stuck in redirect loops.

Does anybody know if this should be possible without too much hacking?

Comment: I was with you right up to the last paragraph.  It sounded as though you wanted the URL of the sites within your network to be `www.mydomain.com/multi/sitename`, until you said "changing their site url afterwards to be outside the multisite root".  I'm not sure which you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The "Be Aware" section here might be helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#WordPress_Settings_Requirements

Comment: Sorry, I thought that might have sounded confusing after I'd published it! Let me try and be clearer:

The multisite install DOES support allowing Wordpress to have its own directory. So I can have my WP core files in
www.mydomain.com/wordpress/
But my network site root might be
www.mydomain.com/mysite/

However, whether your site URL is the same as your wordpress URL, it seems that all the other sites on the network must be below the site URL e.g.
www.mydomain.com/mysite/site1/
www.mydomain.com/mysite/site2/
www.mydomain.com/mysite/site3/

Comment: I would like to have my core wordpress installation at
www.mydomain.com/wordpress/

Then the sites in my network at

www.mydomain.com/site1/
www.mydomain.com/site2/
www.mydomain.com/site3/

Comment: That clarifies it quite a bit.  I seem to recall discussing a very similar need on a different WP MS question a few months back.  Let me dig around and see if I can come up with anything helpful.

Comment: In your example do you have a separate site running in the root www.mydomain.com?  It sounds like you are certainly familiar with how to run WP in a directory but having it's URL in the root.  If there is no other to serve up from the root, have your base network as the root and your network sites as www.mydomain.com/site1, www.mydomain.com/site2, etc.

Comment: Quite possible I'm missing something in your situation but I just did this last week for a client who is opening franchises across the country.  We converted an old single WP install to multi-site with the parent in the root and each city running as domain.com/city, domain.com/city2.

Comment: Yeah, we already have a site running in the root, so can't go messing about with the index.php or .htaccess files in the root, unfortunately. I thought I'd cracked it when I read about setting up wordpress in a different directory, but I think it might just not be possible.

Comment: I could probably come up with some creative .htaccess rules to map requests from /site1/ to /wordpress/ but there's always going to be problems with the admin area when it tries to link to different sites and admin areas within the network.